# The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, visual-studio-2017

After I upgraded the `Xamarin.Forms` version in my Xamarin Forms PCL project from 2.x to 3.x I got the following error message which prevent me from building the UWP project.

> The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

The strange thing about this is that I could build the `Android` and `iOS` projects.

Any ideas what I could do to get the UWP project working, too?

Comment: I take it you did this: `You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard`? :)

Comment: But netstandard isn't a nuget package how should I add it?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/

Comment: @HansPassant I have this one already installed :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case I changed the min version of the UWP SDK to 1709 (`Fall Creators Update`) Build 16299 and I was able to build my UWP project again.

Previously I used a lower UWP SDK version.

As you see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version) in this version Microsoft added `.NET Standard 2.0` support for `Windows`.