# Missing netstandard 2.0 reference in Xamarin.Forms project when building with Jenkins

Tags: .net, visual-studio, jenkins, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I'm getting over 1500 errors like this, when I try to build an updated `Xamarin.Forms` project with `Jenkins`:

> App.xaml.cs(24,32): error CS0012: Der Typ "Object" ist in einer nicht referenzierten Assembly definiert. Fügen Sie einen Verweis auf die Assembly "netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" hinzu.

Translated error:

> CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

If I build the project with the same machine, but within `Visual Studio 2017` it works without problems (as on my local machine). The build command for `Jenkins` looks like this

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild" /p:ReferencePath=C:\jenkins\workspace\somelibrary\ SomeProject/SomeProject/SomeProject.csproj /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release /t:Build
```

Previously I [updated to `.NET Standard 2.0`](https://montemagno.com/how-to-convert-a-pcl-library-to-net-standard-and-keep-git-history/) and `Xamarin.Forms 3.4.0.1039999`. The build server itself is running on <s>`Windows 10 1703`</s>`Windows 10 1909`. <s>I have `UWP` in my `Xamarin.Forms` project, but I'm not really using it.</s> (I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51250200/426227) that you need at least `Windows 10 1709` if you want to use `.NET Standard 2.0` together with `UWP`.)

The project is also referencing a `NuGet` package, which isn't compatible with `.NET Standard 2.0` yet. Here I get the warning

> Warning    NU1701  Package 'xxx' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

This could be a reason why there are some problems, because it is [not fully compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

What I tried:

- clean build, deleted `bin` and `obj` folder
- use of `<Reference Include="netstandard" />` without success at building with Jenkins. Reference to `NETStandard.Library` throws a warning in my local build environment (but it is installed)
- updated `Visual Studio Build Tools 2017` and `Visual Studio 2017` to the latest version (15.9.18)
- installed `.NET Core SDK`, `.NET Core Build Tools`, `.NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK` on the build server
- extended `PATH` environment variable with *C:\Program Files\dotnet*, set global environment variable `MSBuildSDKsPath` to *C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.509\Sdks*
- deleted UWP project (still exists on folder, but not in *.sln)
- made some research after similar problems from other users, but didn't find something that solved the issue

What I observed:

- building the project works fine with `Visual Studio 2017` on the build server with `Windows 10 1703`
- building the project works fine with `Visual Studio 2017` on my local machine with `Windows 10 1809`
- building the project works fine with `msbuild` and command line on the build server (NuGet packages references correctly netstandard2.0 instead of netstandard1.3 and so on in the NuGetFallbackFolder)

What I could try:

- <s>update the build server to `Windows 10 1709` or higher</s>
- replace/update the library, which still uses `.NET 4.6.1`
- upgrade to `Visual Studio 2019`
- create a `.NET Standard` project from scratch and copy all files over (and loosing `GIT` history)

But what I don't get is that it is working fine in `Visual Studio` but not with `msbuild`/`Jenkins`. Seems that a reference is missing or something is not installed.

What should I do?

**Edit:**

Extract of the *.csproj* from the Xamarin.Forms part of the project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
    <AssemblySearchPaths>
        $(AssemblySearchPaths);
        $(ReferencePath);
    </AssemblySearchPaths>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="picture.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin" Version="5.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="SomeLibrary">
      <HintPath>pat\to\library\netstandard2.0\SomeLibrary.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="Common\Localization\AppResources.Designer.cs">
            <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
            <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
            <DependentUpon>AppResources.resx</DependentUpon>
        </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Update="Common\Localization\AppResources.de.resx">
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
        </EmbeddedResource>
        <EmbeddedResource Update="Common\Localization\AppResources.resx">
            <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
            <LastGenOutput>AppResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
            <SubType>Designer</SubType>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Update="App.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </None>
      <None Update="SomePage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can your share the references from your `csproj` file?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: I edited my question. Let me know if you need something. The platform specific *csproj* looks different (old format).

Comment: Which package causes an `Warning NU1701` error? Also, how did you restore the packages and build the sources, which commands are used? Also this [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/139572/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-netstandard-when-jenkins-builds-ios-project) might be helpful

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: [XLog](https://github.com/Belorus/XLog). Restoring is done with `msbuild` and `/t:Restore` as shown above. There are multiple things in the build process involved. The main part consists of building the Xamarin.Forms project first with `msbuild /p:ReferencePath=xxx SomeProject/SomeProject/SomeProject.csproj /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release /t:Build`and then the Android project with `msbuild /p:ReferencePath=xxx SomeProject/SomeProject.Droid/SomeProject.Droid.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:Restore /t:PackageForAndroid /t:Build`. But he get's the errors at the first step

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable is pointing to `C:\Program Files\dotnet` on the build server.

Comment: .net standard 2.0 support was added with 1709, so update Win10 to 1903/1909

Comment: @magicandre1981: updated Windows but still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it with this

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild" SomeProject/SomeProject/SomeProject.csproj /t:Restore /p:Configuration=Release

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild" /p:ReferencePath=C:\jenkins\workspace\somelibrary\ SomeProject/SomeProject/SomeProject.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:Build
```

So the solution is to make two calls: one for `restore` and one for `build`. I do this for the Xamarin.Forms project and platform specific project separately.